# Maven 2 - define dependency version from transitive dependency version

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, dependency-management

I'll explain the question with my real situation.

I use logback 1.0.1 for logging, and it includes SLF4J 1.6.4 as a dependency. I also use the SLF4J API bridges for legacy logging API's (java.util.logging, log4j and commons-logging), which are not explicit dependencies. These must also (preferrably) be version 1.6.4.

Trying to make my pom.xml as neat and error-free as possible, I'd like to enforce that these API bridges be the same version as SLF4J. The only way I know is to manually define them as dependencies in my pom.xml using version 1.6.4. If I ever update logback and the required SLF4J version is raised, I'd need to remember to change the bridge API's to the proper version.

Can I somehow hook the legacy API's version to the version of the transitive dependency SLF4J?

Current pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.4</org.slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <!-- requires SLF4J 1.6.4 -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <!-- here, how to bind this version value to SLF4J's version? -->
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- the other two bridge API's go here -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891067/maven-access-version-of-transitive-dependency-via-property

Answer (score 1):

Not in a very beautiful way :/

There is the maven enforcer plugin: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/

so you can ban the transitive dependencies and include the version you want: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html

If you use a property for the good version you dont need to mess around in the enforcer plugin version.

Comment: I looked at the enforcer, but it is not really what I need. If I simply define SLF4J in my pom, I'll get the same result. It works, but not 'automagically' with logback upgrades, I'll need to change SLF4J version too. Functional, but not a beautiful way... ;-)

Comment: jepp! thing is this does not prevent people from changing versions of transitive dependencies by adding them directly. If you ban those you are sure no one is able to do that. But that might not be an issue :)

Answer (score 1):

[Dependency Convergence](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) may help you. Thank you @wemu!

I have a [same? problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33813496/330457).

You can clone https://gist.github.com/f35db1ac6dc8b6f45393.git

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope> <!-- depends on slf4j-api:1.7.7 -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${unified.slf4j-api.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${unified.slf4j-api.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <unified.slf4j-api.version>1.7.7</unified.slf4j-api.version>
</properties>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.1</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>enforce</id>
           <configuration>
             <rules>
               <dependencyConvergence/>
             </rules>
           </configuration>
           <goals>
             <goal>enforce</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

At this point, things just work.

```
$ mvn -Dverbose=true dependency:tree verify
...
[INFO] test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (default) @ enforcer-dependency-convergence-test ---
[INFO]
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...

$
```

Now let's change the `slf4j-api`'s version.

```
$ mvn -Dunified.slf4j-api.version=1.7.13 -Dverbose=true dependency:tree verify
...
[INFO] test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.13)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (default) @ enforcer-dependency-convergence-test ---
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 paths to dependency are:
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
and
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.13
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
and
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 paths to dependency are:
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
and
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.13
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
and
+-test:enforcer-dependency-convergence-test:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't directly depend on slf4j in your top level pom.

Comment: I need the bridge API's, and I can depend on SLF4J directly or not, but the chance of version mismatch remains, as I'll need to define both versions manually. If tying both versions/libs simply can't be done yet because nobody coded something like this so far, so I'll have to cope with it.