# Maven: access version of transitive dependency via property

Tags: java, maven, ant, properties

In a Maven project, one of my direct dependency has an indirect dependency com.foo:bar.
What I need, is a Maven property (e.g. `${bar-version}`) with the version number of this artifact. I need this mechanism for the version numbers of several indirect dependencies.

I learned from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359872/can-i-use-the-path-to-a-maven-dependency-as-a-property) that I can access the local path of the artifact's jar with `${maven.dependency.com.foo.bar.jar.path}` within the antrun plugin. The workaround I am using now, is to parse its value (e.g. `/path/to/repository/com/foo/bar/2.1.1/bar-2.1.1.jar`) within an antrun execution and define a property there (configuration `exportAntProperties` is my friend). However, since there is no good string regex manipulation in ant per default, this is quite cumbersome.

Are there other properties like `${maven.dependency.com.foo.bar.jar.path}` available? I tried `${maven.dependency.com.foo.bar.jar.version}`, but it did not work. I would also like to understand the mechanism behind this property. Is it backed by Java Classes? Like `project.organization.name`  is `getProject().getOrganizarion().getName()` in the corresponding Maven Classes...

Any help welcome!

Thanks,
Johannes

Comment: Use dependencyManagement to influence the transitive dependencies. Or you can explicit add those indirect deps to your own pom so they will fixed.

Comment: I do not want to influence/override the dependencies. I want to have exactly the version of com.foo:bar that my direct dependency is using.

Comment: Than just write it into your pom file.

Comment: That is prone to typos - I could use a wrong version by accident. In addition, I want to have it updated automatically when I use a newer version of my direct dependency. It is not only one dependency, there are 5 indirect dependency version numbers I want to extract.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861242/maven-2-define-dependency-version-from-transitive-dependency-version