# Can I refer one of transitive dependency's version in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

Let's say I have a project whose `dependency:tree` prints like this.

```
[INFO] group:a:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- group:b:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- group:c:jar:1.0:compile
```

Can I refer `group:c:version` which is `1.0` in `group:a`'s `pom.xml`?

I know it's weird but I'm facing this [situation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/66).

Comment: This was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23891067/1743880) with no answer, but that's because I don't think it is possible. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14861242/1743880) might be relevant also.

Comment: Answered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815038/330457

Comment: @JinKwon You should close this question if you've answered it elsewhere.